# Google cloud platform Kotlin Spring App tutorial

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-platform

I finished the  [Build a Kotling Spring Application with Google Cloud Platform](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-cloud-gcp-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0), where we create an application that accepts registrants information, publishes it to a Cloud Pub/Sub topic, and persists this to a Cloud MySQL database.

I would like to know how would you delete a registrant from the database. I know in Java it would be

```
 @DeleteRegistrant("{lastName}")
void delete () {
    registrant.delete(lastName);
}
```

I am wondering if anyone could help me how it would look like in kotlin.

Comment: Can't you just write the very same function in Kotlin?
`@DeleteRegistrant("{lastName}") fun delete(): Unit { registrant.delete(lastName) }`

Comment: I tried doing this

`@DeleteMapping("/deleteRegistrant")
  fun deleteRegistrant(
    @RequestParam("firstName") firstName: String,
    @RequestParam("lastName") lastName: String,
    @RequestParam("email") email: String): RedirectView{
      registrantRepository.delete(Registrant(firstName,lastName, email))
      return RedirectView("/registrants")
  }`
Where I fill in a html form for these requests then delete that registrant with those details but nothing happens. It compiles but database doesn't get the message.

Comment: @CFrei, I think the error is that the html form is used, and that should be used for the http post method, not delete, I should get the Registrant's details a different way.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in [this tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/kotlin-spring-boot-mysql-jpa-hibernate-rest-api-tutorial/) you can have something like this in your kotlin app

```
@DeleteRegistrant("{id}")
fun deleteRegistrantById(@PathVariable(value = "id") regId: Long): ResponseEntity<Void> {

    return registrantRepository.findById(regId).map { reg  ->
        registrantRepository.delete(reg)
        ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK)
    }.orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())

}
```